# Upgrading cordova 1.9.0 (iOS) to cordova 2.1.0 and updating existing projects to use 2.1.0

Tags: ios5, cordova, ios6, xcode4.5

I have uninstalled cordova 1.9.0 by doing:

To uninstall:

1. Remove the PHONEGAPLIB value in Xcode Preferences -> Source Trees
2. Delete the ~/Documents/PhoneGapLib folder
3. Delete the ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/PhoneGap folder
4. Delete the "~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Application/PhoneGap-based Application.xctemplate" or the "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project\ Templates/Application/PhoneGap-based\ Application.xctemplate" folder
5. Delete the /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework folder
   Delete the ~/Library/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework symlink

I then followed the upgrade guides:
http://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md
and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html
**The project builds with no errors**, but when I try to run:
On an iPhone with  iOS 5.1.1 I get this error:

```
ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found.
```

and on an iPhone with iOS 6.0 I get this error:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Whether I remove the only external link or all javascript sources, whether I manually add the www folder, or anything at all that can be found on the internet, these errors are persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this problem was first noticed in cordova 1.4 and I followed this solution http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/02/16/linked-source-files-across-phonegap-projects-on-osx/
The problem was that Xcode could not see the www folder.